# could not resolve hostname

Tags: dns, connection, hostname, resolve

We have a webapp runs on Centos server. Our server is located in Germany and our webapp's hostname is located in Dns service provider in USA.

hostname : www.chooseclick.com

Some of our clients cannot access our website but most of them can . The clients that gets the error are mostly has a proxy server running at their network. 
But when they try to access via servers ip address (62.75.230.187) they can access to website.

What would be the problem ?

(Ssl not active right now so https://www.chooseclick.com is not working. So you must try with http://www.chooseclick.com)

Answer (score 1):

looks like it's a DNS issue for that specific host (www.chooseclick) since i can definitely confirm the domain name is valid via whois (below) and because network testing commands like 'ping' can't resolve the name. talk to whomever controls your DNS records for that host.

```
wintermute:~ 08:56:29 melgart$ whois chooseclick.com

Whois Server Version 2.0

Domain names in the .com and .net domains can now be registered
with many different competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net
for detailed information.

   Domain Name: CHOOSECLICK.COM
   Registrar: WILD WEST DOMAINS, LLC
   Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 440
   Whois Server: whois.wildwestdomains.com
   Referral URL: http://www.wildwestdomains.com
   Name Server: NS10.NAMESERVERSERVICE.DE
   Name Server: NS9.NAMESERVERSERVICE.DE
   Status: clientDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
   Status: clientRenewProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientRenewProhibited
   Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
   Status: clientUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
   Updated Date: 21-apr-2016
   Creation Date: 10-jan-2007
   Expiration Date: 10-jan-2020

>>> Last update of whois database: Sat, 12 Nov 2016 13:56:27 GMT <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp

NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the
registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is
currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration
date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring
registrar.  Users may consult the sponsoring registrar's Whois database to
view the registrar's reported date of expiration for this registration.

TERMS OF USE: You are not authorized to access or query our Whois
database through the use of electronic processes that are high-volume and
automated except as reasonably necessary to register domain names or
modify existing registrations; the Data in VeriSign Global Registry
Services' ("VeriSign") Whois database is provided by VeriSign for
information purposes only, and to assist persons in obtaining information
about or related to a domain name registration record. VeriSign does not
guarantee its accuracy. By submitting a Whois query, you agree to abide
by the following terms of use: You agree that you may use this Data only
for lawful purposes and that under no circumstances will you use this Data
to: (1) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass
unsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations via e-mail, telephone,
or facsimile; or (2) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes
that apply to VeriSign (or its computer systems). The compilation,
repackaging, dissemination or other use of this Data is expressly
prohibited without the prior written consent of VeriSign. You agree not to
use electronic processes that are automated and high-volume to access or
query the Whois database except as reasonably necessary to register
domain names or modify existing registrations. VeriSign reserves the right
to restrict your access to the Whois database in its sole discretion to ensure
operational stability.  VeriSign may restrict or terminate your access to the
Whois database for failure to abide by these terms of use. VeriSign
reserves the right to modify these terms at any time.

The Registry database contains ONLY .COM, .NET, .EDU domains and
Registrars.
Domain Name: CHOOSECLICK.COM
Registry Domain ID: 748038317_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.wildwestdomains.com
Registrar URL: http://www.wildwestdomains.com
Update Date: 2015-02-19T20:47:25Z
Creation Date: 2007-01-10T11:44:55Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2020-01-10T11:44:55Z
Registrar: Wild West Domains, LLC
Registrar IANA ID: 440
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse@wildwestdomains.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.4806242505
Reseller: Domains Priced Right
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
Domain Status: clientRenewProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientRenewProhibited
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
Registry Registrant ID: Not Available From Registry
Registrant Name: Registration Private
Registrant Organization: Domains By Proxy, LLC
Registrant Street: DomainsByProxy.com
Registrant Street: 14747 N Northsight Blvd Suite 111, PMB 309
Registrant City: Scottsdale
Registrant State/Province: Arizona
Registrant Postal Code: 85260
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: +1.4806242599
Registrant Phone Ext:
Registrant Fax: +1.4806242598
Registrant Fax Ext:
Registrant Email: CHOOSECLICK.COM@domainsbyproxy.com
Registry Admin ID: Not Available From Registry
Admin Name: Registration Private
Admin Organization: Domains By Proxy, LLC
Admin Street: DomainsByProxy.com
Admin Street: 14747 N Northsight Blvd Suite 111, PMB 309
Admin City: Scottsdale
Admin State/Province: Arizona
Admin Postal Code: 85260
Admin Country: US
Admin Phone: +1.4806242599
Admin Phone Ext:
Admin Fax: +1.4806242598
Admin Fax Ext:
Admin Email: CHOOSECLICK.COM@domainsbyproxy.com
Registry Tech ID: Not Available From Registry
Tech Name: Registration Private
Tech Organization: Domains By Proxy, LLC
Tech Street: DomainsByProxy.com
Tech Street: 14747 N Northsight Blvd Suite 111, PMB 309
Tech City: Scottsdale
Tech State/Province: Arizona
Tech Postal Code: 85260
Tech Country: US
Tech Phone: +1.4806242599
Tech Phone Ext:
Tech Fax: +1.4806242598
Tech Fax Ext:
Tech Email: CHOOSECLICK.COM@domainsbyproxy.com
Name Server: NS9.NAMESERVERSERVICE.DE
Name Server: NS10.NAMESERVERSERVICE.DE
DNSSEC: signedDelegation
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2016-11-12T13:00:00Z <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en

The data contained in this Registrar's Whois database,
while believed by the registrar to be reliable, is provided "as is"
with no guarantee or warranties regarding its accuracy. This information
is provided for the sole purpose of assisting you in obtaining
information about domain name registration records. Any use of
this data for any other purpose is expressly forbidden without
the prior written permission of this registrar.  By submitting an
inquiry, you agree to these terms of usage and limitations of warranty.
In particular, you agree not to use this data to allow, enable, or
otherwise make possible, dissemination or collection of this data, in
part or in its entirety, for any purpose, such as the transmission of
unsolicited advertising and solicitations of any kind, including spam.
You further agree not to use this data to enable high volume, automated
or robotic electronic processes designed to collect or compile this data
for any purpose, including mining this data for your own personal or
commercial purposes.

Please note: the owner of the domain name is specified in the "registrant" section.
In most cases, the Registrar is not the owner of domain names listed in this database.
```

Comment: thank you i contacted to my DNS service provider and waiting for their answer. Also i have access to dns settings do you think i have any thing to do ?

Comment: if these clients are desperate and *must* access the site while your DNS provider helps you work out the issue, i'd suggest letting them know how to access your website directly using the IP address. for some clients, it's not acceptable to have downtime but in fact, your site isn't down -- merely unreachable by name. they might be happy to have _any_ access.